# How to disable a Windows registry key without deleting it

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu, regedit, registrykey

I wanted to disable an item in Windows context menus so I found the key relating to it. Deleting this key may solve my problem but is there any other way than deleting it would do the work? Perhaps adding a "--" string before its 'default' value?

Comment: 1. Change key access right or 2. make registry key backup, then delete it.

Comment: ok how can I change access right? and Have you heard anything about add a "--" like prefix to the default string value to nullify a registry key?

Comment: You can just change the value and watch for result. Are there any reason you are afraid of?

Comment: @Daemon-5 Actually I do because I'm a beginner. I was afraid to do something irreversible and I am not very comfortable in Importing/Exporting registry keys.

Comment: Anyway if you're gonna work with registry you have to learn how to make [registry backup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows-855140ad-e318-2a13-2829-d428a2ab0692)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the type of verb we are talking about it is hard to give an exact answer.

If it is a static verb (...\xyz\shell\open) then inside the "open" key create one or more of the following empty string values: `Extended`, `LegacyDisable` or `ProgrammaticAccessOnly`.

If this verb has `DropTarget` and/or `DelegateExcute` you might have to rename those.

If it is a dynamic verb (...\xyz\shellex\open) you need to change the guid (subkey or value) to make it invalid. Prepend any character before `{`.

You can also prevent Explorer from reading the key by changing the ACL. Right-click the verb key and select "Permissions" and in the standard security dialog go into advanced mode and deny yourself or your group the query and enumerate access rights.

Answer (score 1):

This is an insane, absolutely twilight zone situation that this plain, direct, simple question with so many coders on the internet cannot get a simple answer. To disable a line of code you prepend with something. Usually this ";". But Microsoft says to "DELETE" a key entry you prepend with "-". And every single time this question is repeated by some bot or bot-head the answer turns into HOW TO DISABLE REGEDIT, or EDITING. My mind is blown for stupid.
We're talking about a key entry, not values - if you disable the key you disable the function and all sub-entries.
So this will be the first last latest or soon to be Alien-vaporized answer: (THREE POSSIBILITIES)

1. Back up the key entry and delete the original.
2. Prepend the key entry with a -
3. SET A DIFFERENT PREPEND - like DISABLED= so all of them will be searchable

I'm gonna do #3.

ALSO: MARK the location as a favorite as another breadcrumb.